# attach folder on docker volume via compose

Tags: docker

I want to attach a subfolder of a volume using docker compose, so, for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
    service:
        image: image-name
        container_name: sample
        volumes:
          - samplevolume/a-folder-on-ftp:/www/html
        restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  samplevolume:
    driver: sapk/plugin-gvfs
    driver_opts:
      url: "ftp://a@b.co"
      password: "pass"
```

Where `a-folder-on-ftp` is an existing folder on the volume as provided by the driver

As best I can tell you can only mount `samplevolume` and not `samplevolume/a-folder-on-ftp` but I can't find documentation explicitly forbidding it.
is this possible?

Comment: Docker in general doesn't allow mounting subdirectories of volumes, Compose or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving samplevolume:/www/html as the volume used on your service, and alter your driver_opts url with something like "ftp://a@b.co/a-folder-on-ftp".